# NuGet.exe from command line gives "existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host" error

Tags: nuget, connection, restore

I'm having problems calling NuGet.exe from the command line:

`nuget.exe restore solution.sln`

On my local machine, this runs without issue from the command line. On the build server, I immediately see the below error:

`An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host`

For background I'm in the process of setting up Jenkins on our build server for our .NET Framework applications.

This error occurs regardless of whether I have Jenkins run the command or I spin up a CMD window (Administrator or otherwise) and run it myself. Even the `-Verbosity detailed` flag comes up with nothing.

Oddly, when doing a restore against the solution within Visual Studio 2017, it works fine.

Has anyone come across this before or have any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So this turned out to be a problem with TLS. Having looked up a lot of articles and knowing some ongoing issues with TLS in various places I found this article:
[Deprecating TLS 1.0 and 1.1 on NuGet.org](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/nuget/deprecating-tls-1-0-and-1-1-on-nuget-org/)

I applied the registry changes mentioned there (as below) and suddenly I got beyond this error

```
reg add HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.0.30319 /v SystemDefaultTlsVersions /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f /reg:64
reg add HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.0.30319 /v SystemDefaultTlsVersions /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f /reg:32
```

Answer (score 0):

I have seen similar behavior and it was due to our IT Security team blocking that particular domain. I could access it from our dev machines, but the build server (which was running not attached to the domain) was blocking.

Comment: I've left a query with our IT support so hopefully it'll be something as simple as that.