VS2022 Unable to Restore NuGet packages
I am running VS2022 on Windows Server 2022 (Version 21H2 - OS Build 20348.2340) on an existing application. When I load the app it tries to restore the nuGet pkgs but I am getting the following error:
Failed to download package 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.WsFederation.8.0.4' from 
'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.wsfederation/8.0.4/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.wsfederation.8.0.4.nupkg'.
Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

This happens for every nuget pkg in the application. I have tried the following:

Reinstalled Visual Studio
"Clear All NuGet Storage" in NuGet Package Manager Settings
Deleted C:\Users\MyUser\AppData\roaming\NuGet
Deleted C:\Users\MyUser\AppData\local\NuGet
Verified TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 exists   in
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Cryptography\Configuration\SSL\00010002
Ensured the registry key exists for
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft.NETFramework\v4.0.30319 /v
SystemDefaultTlsVersions /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f /reg:64

I can download directly by copying the url in a browser on the server and it downloads that individual package i.e. https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.wsfederation/8.0.4/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.wsfederation.8.0.4.nupkg  but I cannot get VS2022 to update the packages either in build or opening the application.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61593426/nuget-exe-from-command-line-gives-existing-connection-was-forcibly-closed-by-th

I also did the reg key add suggested by Hans Passant but that didnt resolve the issue. I would assume since I can download the pkg from the browser there is not security policy in place preventing access. It has to be something specific to VS?

Just checking - Are you sure you are running as an Administrator? Weird things happen if I open a solution directly where some projects and dependencies/packages don't get loaded.

Yes I run VS as Admin, also opened the cmd as admin to add reg key

Am also getting the same issues.  VS2019 doesn't have the issues even with the same 'source' settings.
